# Работа с двумя формами. Передача Label между формами

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

Добрый день!
У меня есть две формы PZ6 и inputForm
Вторая вызывается из первой по нажатию кнопки.

```
private void inputButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  inputForm change = new inputForm();
  input.Show();
}
```

В PZ6 у меня есть label называемый ValuesLabel, туда выводятся значения.
Как сделать, чтобы после закрытия inputForm эти значения обновлялись.
Пытался прописать это в самой inputForm, но не получилось.
Пытался прописать как метод в PZ6.cs, ругается на то, что ValuesLabel не static.
Есть идеи?

Comment: А какие значения? Откуда они берутся? // Вы не должны из новой формы пытаться обновить старую. Пусть старая форма себя и обновляет.

Comment: @VladD, ну у меня вводятся два int значения и всё.
вот скрин: [https://pp.vk.me/c637219/v637219189/29ed3/lqkoQgsA6dE.jpg]

Comment: @VladD, я не хочу в ней, я хочу чтобы после Close() для inputForm, в PZ6 у меня обновлялся Label.
Вроде как можно условие сделать от результата закрытия окна.

Answer (score 1):

Может быть, вам нужно вот что:

```
using (inputForm change = new inputForm())
{
    var result = change.ShowDialog(this);
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        var firstValue = change.ИмяВашейПервойМетки;
        var secondValue = change.ИмяВашейВторойМетки;
        // ну и пишите эти значения куда надо
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из способов - это предоставить классу формы inputForm объект формы PZ6.
Добавьте в конструктор inputForm параметр типа PZ6 и передавайте туда экземпляр данной формы. Тогда вы сможете манипулировать формой PZ6 из inputForm.

Будет выглядеть примерно так:

```
public class PZ6
{
    public string ValuesLabel;

    private void inputButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      inputForm change = new inputForm(this);
      input.Show();
    }
}

public class inputForm
{
    // Приватное поле для взаимодействия с PZ6
    private PZ6 _pz6;

    // Конструктор принимает объект PZ6
    public inputForm(PZ6 pz6)
    {
      this._pz6 = pz6;
    }

    // Изменить текст метки
    public void ChangeLabel(string value)
    {
        _pz6.ValuesLabel.Text = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Идея отличная, но вот в чём проблема,  у меня ругается на уровень защиты для ValuesLabel, а где его изменить я не знаю.

Comment: Нашёл где стояло Private